# What is the difference between JPA Transaction and Hibernate Transacation and Spring Transaction? and which one is more advantageous?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I would really like to know about this difference and I know we use spring transaction for all purposes other than database transaction also apart from JMS like wise I want to know the *in-depth* difference between all the 3 types of the transaction if possible please provide with code and explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with the Spring transaction architecture so I will reserve my comments *primarily* for JPA and Hibernate. Now the JPA is actually an interface that is implemented. It provides a standard API for transaction processing. Thus Hibernate would implement the JPA as would many other providers.

Hibernate is a ORM system in that it maps Java Objects to a Relational Database. The transaction system Hibernate relies upon is primarily provided by the underlying Relational Database {PosgreSQL, Oracle, SqlServer, et al}. Note that Relational Databases provide transactions for CUD (Create, Update Delete) operations and not R reads unlike some NO-SQL systems.

Finally, from a quick glance at Google, Spring transactions *appear* to be the Spring equivalent to JPA only for any POJO (Plain Old Java Object). I could be wrong but that's what it appears at quick glance.

I could provide more detail but I think that's sufficient and more detail might confuse you.

The important take aways are:

- Understand what is an Interface and what is an Implementation.
- Understand that the underlying relational database provides the transaction system. Ex: when you *rollback* a commit it's the database doing the heavy lifting and not Hibernate
- Understand that the limits and capabilities of the transaction is *primarily* an artifact of the limits and capabilities of the relational database providing this functionality regardless of the interfaces you use.